# Broken links in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver, broken-links

I am changing the url structure of a website, to have it extensionless.
For example:

```
example[.]com/hello.html
```

would become:

```
example[.]com/hello
```

I have everything set up in my .htaccess file, and all works perfectly. However I want to drop the .html throughout the website, rather than by using a 301 redirect everything.

I tested it on a few pages and published them, it works fine online, however locally it doesn't know where to search, plus it's being counted as a broken link.

Is there a way to tell Dreamweaver not to look at the ".html" when viewing links?  So that when I search for broken links it doesn't report false positives?

Thanks for any help, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to see the result, I would suggest you to use a free FTP. As for the ".html" links you may show the name without html but for linking you do need to link it to the proper link.